# How to add html code css/js in main layout of Magento 2.1?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, magento

I have Magento version 2.1 with default theme. Uploaded in shared server (not localhost).

Αlthough I have seen bootstrap.js the css isn't there! Css of bootstrap didn't apply in my web page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="mage/bootstrap" src="http://magentoeshop.vtsoulis.gr/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/el_GR/mage/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I have 2 questions:

1) How to put the css (bootstrap) file in the main layout or activated?
2) How to put any css(link) or js(script) in head section or js after body section?

I am web php developer but I dont know where is the file to configure as a custom code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add custom css/js file, you must set up a custom theme.

1. Create theme: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html
2. **Make sure that you set your Magento application to the developer mode.**
3. Add the following folders to your custom theme

As below:

```
app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / Magento_Theme / layout
app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css
```

Create the following files:

```
app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / Magento_Theme / layout / default_head_blocks.xml
app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css / local-m.css
app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css / local-l.css
```

place this code within **default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <!-- Add external resources -->
    <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" src_type="url" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
    <!-- Add custom styles -->
    <css src="css/local-m.css" />
    <css src="css/local-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
  </head>
</page>
```

4. Apply your theme: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html
5. Deploy static resources (SSH to magento root).

As below:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

References:

1. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html
2. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2